# Find/create correct enddate for series of tracking records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

This one is a doozy, so stick with me.

I have two tables that track people in locations.  I've successfully merged them using LEAD and LAG to create a seamless transition in a single table.
My issue now is that for one of the tables, there are additional activity items I need to include, which sit within some segments.
So for simplicity, I have the following normal case:

```
| System |  ID | Item |         Start         |         End
|  Alpha | 987 |  123 | May, 20 2015 07:00:00 | May, 20 2015 08:00:00 
|  Alpha | 374 |  123 | May, 20 2015 08:00:00 | May, 20 2015 10:00:00 
|  Beta  | 184 |  123 | May, 20 2015 10:00:00 | May, 20 2015 11:00:00 
|  Beta  | 798 |  123 | May, 20 2015 11:00:00 | May, 20 2015 12:00:00
```

Now, these extra items sit WITHIN certain records, so the data I have looks something like this:

```
| System   |  ID | Item |         Start         |         End
|  Alpha   | 987 |  123 | May, 20 2015 07:00:00 | May, 20 2015 08:00:00 
|  Alpha   | 374 |  123 | May, 20 2015 08:00:00 | May, 20 2015 10:00:00 
|  Beta    | 184 |  123 | May, 20 2015 10:00:00 | May, 20 2015 11:00:00 
|  Charlie | 874 |  123 | May, 20 2015 10:20:00 | May, 20 2015 10:25:00  
|  Charlie | 984 |  123 | May, 20 2015 10:37:00 | May, 20 2015 10:54:00  
|  Beta    | 798 |  123 | May, 20 2015 11:00:00 | May, 20 2015 12:00:00
```

Note that the two Charlie events occur within Beta 184.

I've currently got the table exploded into a record for every minute (needed for the next step, don't ask)  and have it displaying the correct records when in that form, but I can't get my head around how to then put it back together and have the correct start and end times on each segment.
Also, somehow new records are going to be formed to fill the gaps.

My desired end result of the above situation is this:

```
| System   |  ID | Item |         Start         |         End
|  Alpha   | 987 |  123 | May, 20 2015 07:00:00 | May, 20 2015 08:00:00 |
|  Alpha   | 374 |  123 | May, 20 2015 08:00:00 | May, 20 2015 10:00:00 |
|  Beta    | 184 |  123 | May, 20 2015 10:00:00 | May, 20 2015 10:20:00 |
|  Charlie | 874 |  123 | May, 20 2015 10:20:00 | May, 20 2015 10:25:00 |
|  Beta    | 184 |  123 | May, 20 2015 10:25:00 | May, 20 2015 10:37:00 | new
|  Charlie | 984 |  123 | May, 20 2015 10:37:00 | May, 20 2015 10:54:00 | 
|  Beta    | 184 |  123 | May, 20 2015 10:54:00 | May, 20 2015 11:00:00 | new
|  Beta    | 798 |  123 | May, 20 2015 11:00:00 | May, 20 2015 12:00:00 |
```

Does this make sense?

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: You should have built the Start and End column into a `View` instead of a physical `Table`.

Comment: I don't understand how a view would help me sorry

Comment: Create a view for merging two tables that track people in locations. Read the view instead of the new table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
DECLARE @Source TABLE (
    [System] VARCHAR(50),
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Item INT NOT NULL,
    Start DATETIME NOT NULL,
    [End] DATETIME NOT NULL,
    CHECK (Start<[End])
)

INSERT INTO @Source (System, ID, Item, Start, [End]) VALUES ('Alpha',   987, 123, '2015-05-20 07:00', '2015-05-20 08:00')
INSERT INTO @Source (System, ID, Item, Start, [End]) VALUES ('Alpha',   374, 123, '2015-05-20 08:00', '2015-05-20 10:00')
--INSERT INTO @Source (System, ID, Item, Start, [End]) VALUES   ('Delta',   555, 123, '2015-05-20 09:30', '2015-05-20 10:00')
INSERT INTO @Source (System, ID, Item, Start, [End]) VALUES ('Beta',    184, 123, '2015-05-20 10:00', '2015-05-20 11:00')
--INSERT INTO @Source (System, ID, Item, Start, [End]) VALUES   ('Charlie', 111, 123, '2015-05-20 10:05', '2015-05-20 10:07')
--INSERT INTO @Source (System, ID, Item, Start, [End]) VALUES   ('Charlie', 222, 123, '2015-05-20 10:10', '2015-05-20 10:20')
INSERT INTO @Source (System, ID, Item, Start, [End]) VALUES ('Charlie', 874, 123, '2015-05-20 10:20', '2015-05-20 10:25')
INSERT INTO @Source (System, ID, Item, Start, [End]) VALUES ('Charlie', 984, 123, '2015-05-20 10:37', '2015-05-20 10:54')
INSERT INTO @Source (System, ID, Item, Start, [End]) VALUES ('Beta',    798, 123, '2015-05-20 11:00', '2015-05-20 12:00')

;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM @Source s1
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT MIN(s2.Start) AS NextStart
        FROM @Source s2
        WHERE s2.Start>s1.Start AND s2.Start<s1.[End]
    ) q2
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT MAX(s3.[End]) AS PreviousEnd
        FROM @Source s3
        WHERE s3.[End]>s1.Start AND s3.[End]<s1.[End]
    ) q3
)
SELECT System, ID, Item, Start, [End]
FROM CTE WHERE NextStart IS NULL AND PreviousEnd IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT System, ID, Item, Start, NextStart
FROM CTE WHERE NextStart IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT System, ID, Item, PreviousEnd, [End]
FROM CTE WHERE PreviousEnd IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT s4.System, s4.ID, s4.Item, q5.[End], q6.Start
FROM @Source s4
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT *
    FROM @Source s5
    WHERE s5.Start>s4.Start AND s5.Start<s4.[End]
) q5
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM @Source s6
    WHERE s6.Start>q5.Start AND s6.Start<s4.[End]
    ORDER BY s6.Start
) q6
WHERE q5.[End]<q6.Start
ORDER BY [Start]
```

The first part of the UNION processes the intervals which are not overlapped with any other intervals.

The second part processes the rows that are overlapped at the end of the interval.

The third part processes the rows that are overlapped at the beginning of the interval.

The last part produces the gap between two other intervals that are overlapping with the base interval (when the two intervals are not adjacent).

Answer (score 1):

It seems @RazvanSocol beat me, but since I made this and it looks simpler than his, I'll post it here too:

```
create table #times (
  Item int,
  EndTime datetime,
  primary key (Item, EndTime)
)

insert into #times 
select distinct Item, StartTime from timetable 
union 
select distinct Item, EndTime from timetable

;with CTE as (
  select
    System, ID, Item, StartTime
  from
    timetable T1
union all
  select
    T1.System, T1.ID, T1.Item, T2.EndTime
  from
    timetable T1
    join timetable T2 on T1.Item = T2.Item and 
        T1.StartTime < T2.StartTime and T1.EndTime > T2.EndTime
  where
    -- This check added to handle cases with adjacent ranges in the dates
    -- as pointed out by Razvan Socol
    not exists (select 1 from timetable T3 where T3.StartTime = T2.EndTime)

)

select
  System, ID, Item, StartTime, E.EndTime
from 
  CTE
  outer apply (
    select top 1 EndTime from #times T
    where T.Item = CTE.Item and T.EndTime > CTE.StartTime 
    order by EndTime asc
  ) E
order by Item, StartTime
```

I used a temp. table to collect all distinct start/end times per item, then used second select in the CTE to create the missing rows and the outer apply in the end recalculates end dates for each row by searching the earliest date found for that item.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/de699/3)

Edit: Added check for adjacent ranges

Comment: If the overlapping rows are adjacent (like the rows with the ID-s 222 and 874 in my script), your query produces duplicate results (in the 10:20 - 10:25 interval we also get Beta, not only Charlie).

Comment: @RazvanSocol Yes that's true, this version will not work if there's several rows with the exact same start time -- but if the data is like that, it could easily end up into a situation where it's impossible to determine which one is the correct system

Comment: There are no rows with the same start time in my example. It's just that the next start time is equal to the previous end time. You can try your query using just the rows with the following ID-s: 184, 222 and 874. Instead of 4 intervals, your query produces 5 intervals (with a duplicate10:20 - 10:25 interval).

Comment: @RazvanSocol Oh yes, you're correct. I misread the example. Added check to prevent that in case someone tries to use this

Answer (score -2):

Try  this

[Sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3ebc8/33)

```
;with cte as

(select distinct t1.system,t1.ID,t1.item,t2.start,
ROW_NUMBER()  over(order by t2.start) rownum 
from timetable t1 right join 
(select system,start from timetable 
union all
select system,[end] from timetable )
as t2 on t1.start = t2.start  
)
select 
case when c1.system is null
then
'Beta'
else
c1.system
end as system,
case when c1.id is null
then
'184'
else
c1.id
end as id,
case when c1.item is null
then
'123'
else
c1.item
end as item,c1.start,c2.start as [End] from cte c1 
join cte c2 on c1.rownum = c2.rownum-1 and c1.start != c2.start
order by c1.rownum;
```

Comment: Well this assumes that all the extra events are Beta, 184 and 123. I would assume that's really not the case